# Why does a smaller margin appear on the right side and bottom when adding a UIBezierPath as a mask to a UIView for the first time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Every time I instantiate a UIView and add a UIBezierPath as a mask using the roundSpecificCorners:withRadius: function, the view seems to have a smaller margin on the right side and bottom, causing it not to cover the entire view as expected.

```
@implementation LoginAccountViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initial setup of the view
    enterEmailView.inputTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Email";
    enterPasswordView.inputTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Password";
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    // Apply corner rounding on the main view
    [mainViewContainer roundSpecificCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight withRadius:10.0];
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Apply corner rounding when changing orientation
        UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *)self.view.window.windowScene;
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = windowScene.interfaceOrientation;
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
            [weakSelf.mainViewContainer roundSpecificCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight withRadius:10.0];
        } else {
            [weakSelf.mainViewContainer roundSpecificCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight withRadius:10.0];
        }
    } completion:nil];
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}

@end

@implementation UIView (CustomLoader)

// Other functions here...

- (void)roundSpecificCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    // Apply a layer mask with corner rounding
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)].CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    // Adjust the autoresizingMask to allow for size changes
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                            UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
}
```

Why does this behavior occur and how can I fix it so that the view covers the entire screen without any additional margins?

here is an image [image]

my view is made by GUI this is the image of my stack of views , the last view is mainViewContainer

[image: Stack view container]

---

Revised results:

[image]

[image: Stack view container]

Comment: Please update your question showing how you create and setup `mainViewContainer`.

Comment: Is updated @HangarRash .

Comment: So `mainViewContainer` is a view inside a view inside a stack view which is in another stack view? Are there any constraints on `mainViewContainer` to size and position it within its parent view? When using constraints, do not also set the `autoresizingMask`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you end up calling `roundSpecificCorners` when auto-layout has not yet set the final frame / bounds.

You will find it ***much easier*** to use a `UIView` subclass that updates the corners on its own.

Quick example:

```
@interface RoundedCornersView : UIView
@end

@implementation RoundedCornersView
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)].CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
@end
```

In Storyboard, select that view and assign its **Custom Class** to `RoundedCornersView`, and your view controller becomes:

```
@interface LoginAccountViewController ()
@end

@implementation LoginAccountViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initial setup of the view
    //enterEmailView.inputTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Email";
    //enterPasswordView.inputTextField.placeholder = @"Enter Password";
}

@end
```

You can remove the `@implementation UIView (CustomLoader)` completely, as well as everything in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

---

In fact, by using a few `IBInspectable` properties and making that custom view `IB_DESIGNABLE`, you can modify the corners and radii and see it in Storyboard:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface RoundedCornersView : UIView
@property (assign, readwrite) IBInspectable CGFloat radius;
@property (assign, readwrite) IBInspectable BOOL topLeft;
@property (assign, readwrite) IBInspectable BOOL topRight;
@property (assign, readwrite) IBInspectable BOOL bottomLeft;
@property (assign, readwrite) IBInspectable BOOL bottomRight;
@end

@implementation RoundedCornersView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit {
    // dfault values for corners-to-round and radii
    _radius = 10.0;
    _topLeft = YES;
    _topRight = YES;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UIRectCorner corners = 0;
    if (_topLeft) { corners |= UIRectCornerTopLeft; }
    if (_topRight) { corners |= UIRectCornerTopRight; }
    if (_bottomLeft) { corners |= UIRectCornerBottomLeft; }
    if (_bottomRight) { corners |= UIRectCornerBottomRight; }
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(_radius, _radius)].CGPath;
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}

@end
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: It continues not to cover all the space, it still looks strange, and in Lanscape the view completely disappears  @DonMag

Comment: @JaelRuvalcaba - then the problem is with your constraints / layout. Here are two screenshots (corner radius set to 30 to make it easier to see):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZQPj.png ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMiP9.png

Comment: I add a view inside that view that you put , but when I try to put in landscape or portrait I got the same space in the leading, and I erase a lot of constraints

Comment: @JaelRuvalcaba - I added your "second try" images to your original post. Looking at those images, the "rounded corners view" ***does*** size correctly. The UI elements you're adding as subviews are the problem. We can't help you without seeing how you're setting up constraints. Create a new project with **only that view controller** and post it somewhere like GitHub ... then we can see what you're doing, and hopefully correct it for you.

Comment: Solved! , I see that self.bounds = container View.bounds causes the problems, I needed to make the entire view with constraints, the space that was left over in white or whatever color was because when the view was rendered that space was part of the safe area . @DonMag